# Hovering div at top

Tags: html, hover

I want a 100% wide div at the top saying "Website under construction" or stuff like that. When you scroll down the page the div will continue to come down with the page, always staying at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CSS-style `position: fixed; top: 0;`

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I have a problem that the top div you suggested keeps going below(behind) certain other divs on my page, do you know why?

Comment: The problem is with the z-index of the div. Either have this div at the end of your HTML (just before `</body>`) or (more preferably) add a `z-index: 9999` to the CSS. Items with a higher z-index will be in front. Items with same z-index will folow the order in your document.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer may solve your problem. However whilst the website is under construction, why don't you just replace index.html with a simple holding page without such complexity and build your site in a subdirectory or better offline. If you're planning to show partially constructed pages with this, it looks a bit naff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{width:100%; position:fixed; background:red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EzJN9/